# Signal for a class method in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'd like to create a `RACSignal` whenever particular class methods are called. This is easy to do for instance methods (`rac_signalForSelector`) but I can't find a way to do it with class methods. e.g. I'd like to receive a signal on `NSError`'s `errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:` and see what parameters it was created with. But really it should be a general solution so I can see when any class method is called. Access to the resulting instance is optional.